# TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL в хранимой процедуре mysql

Tags: mysql

Для *MS SQL* есть возможность установки `TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL` в хранимых процедурах. Например:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE MySP AS
BEGIN

SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED
BEGIN TRAN  --you are changing isoloation level from default read commited to read uncommited

      SELECT * FROM MyTable

COMMIT TRAN  --back to default isolation level

END
```

А как получить текущий `TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL` в хранимой процедуре *MySQL* и установить новый? Или это в принципе невозможно в *MySQL*, и уровень изоляции транзакции можно задать только на уровне сессии или глобально?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В MySQL уровень изоляции устанавливается так же, как и в MS SQL. [SET TRANSACTION Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/set-transaction.html). Если не указано, что уровень устанавливается глобально или сессионно, то он устанавливается для ближайшей транзакции.

Насчёт возможности получения сведений о текущем уровне изоляции - получите значение глобальной/сессионной tx_isolation. Но какой в этом смысл? не проще ли безусловно установить тот уровень, который необходим?